# Bug in Highcharts xAxis.breaks feature? Or do I misunderstand?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The Highcharts API reference for the [`xAxis.breaks`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.breaks) option describes it as:

> An array defining breaks in the axis, the sections defined will be *left out* and all the points shifted closer to each other.

Emphasis on `left out` are mine.

The subtitle of their referenced [simple breaks fiddle-demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/axisbreak/break-simple/) says `Line should be interrupted between 5 and 10`. Yet the line isn't broken there; there's a line segment connecting the point at x=5 to the point at x=10.

**Question 1:** Is the implementation deviating from the specified behavior or am I misinterpreting what they mean by `left out` and `interrupted`?

In my application, having visible breaks in the line between the points specified in my `xAxis.breaks` array will be important. If someone can confirm that this is a bug, I'll submit it as such.

**Question 2:** If it's *not* a bug is there a way / another option to turn off or hide the line segments corresponding to my specified breaks?

Comment: Look at their advanced example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/axisbreak/break-visualized/

Comment: Aw, man... really? I guess I can understand having to do something like that for breaks in bars on the Y axis, but it seems like an awful lot of work to have to do to simply omit a segment in a line chart...

Comment: Well, the good news is that they've basically done the work for you. You just need to pull in that function, give it a tweak, and then go.

Comment: Hmmm... given that their zigzag lines go _on top of_ their bars, I wonder how much extra I'll need to do to not clobber the point markers while painting out the line segments. Maybe I'll have to redraw the markers too?

Comment: I have found that this breaks (ha!) when using very large spans. Say your lower values all hover around 20-30 but you have a few in the 30,000 range. Good luck getting that to work! http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/bba8ncz5/ for example.

Comment: My attempts can be found here: [demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/9n91b8cq/1/) to [demo 7](http://jsfiddle.net/9n91b8cq/7/) all not working. As written in my deleted answer: Q1: it is not a bug. the documentation says nothing about the line itself but the xAxis. Q2: no idea.

Comment: That's correct, Axis.breaks, won't break line/spline. To break lines, in Highstock, you can use [`gapSize`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.gapSize) option. Or add `null` points to your data when line should be broken (that works also in Highcharts). Just make sure [`connectNulls`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.connectNulls) is set to false.

Comment: @Paweł Fus: The problem I observe in Highcharts is that adding `null` points has no effect on the line segments connecting `from` and `to` points when the x-values of those `null` points lie within the break (i.e., have `from < x < to`), even with `connectNulls` explicitly set to `false`. See http://jsfiddle.net/952u2bh5/1/ .

Comment: Because you have points 6/7/8/9 as nulls. All of them are within that range which is cut, so points are omitted. I think using highstock is the only solution (altogether with `gapSize`): http://jsfiddle.net/952u2bh5/2/

Comment: Or split break into two separate breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/952u2bh5/4/ - now bottom labels sometimes overlap, but this should be avoided by using `tickPositioner` - note `marker.enabled` is set to true, so default hiding markers for high density is disabled.

Comment: Yes, I see that splitting the break and providing an appropriate `tickPositioner` can be made to work: http://jsfiddle.net/952u2bh5/5/ . But such a solution strikes me as being like reaching around one's head to scratch one's ear. Wouldn't it make more sense for the implementation of the line-drawing algorithm to check whether any (or perhaps _all_) points within the break are `null`, and if so, omit the line segment spanning the break? That would seem to be more intuitive behavior than the way it currently works.

Comment: Hard to say, I think actual solution and your solution - both makes sense in certain cases. `breaks` is quite new feature, so there is a lot of space for improvements. Let me create ticket [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4275) and we will see. Feel free to take part in the discussion - your voice is very appreciated! ;)

Comment: @Paweł Fus: Thanks, I've added a comment to the ticket.